# Symfony2 Doctrine query builder use date function

Tags: symfony, dql, doctrine-query

how to use datetime functions in doctrine query builder,the below sql query need convert doctrine query(DQL).

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)) + COUNT(*)) * 60) as hours FROM table_name
```

The below one i have tried

```
$qb = $emClient->createQueryBuilder()->select('SEC_TO_TIME((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, en.startTime, swenendTime)) + COUNT(*)) * 60) as hours')
            ->from('AppBundle:MyEntity', 'en')
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

But i got error undefined keyword at column 0,7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine supports following built-in functions http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates

So either you implement your own functions or use plain SQL query
`$emClient->getConnection()->executeQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use these function either you need to implement them on your own if they don't exist as @Denis Alimov suggested or you can use already implemented function with [Doctrine Extensions Bundle](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions). The last option is get all the data needed and perform some operations on PHP side. You can also execute PURE sql and map it to doctrine with [ResultSetMappingBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder)